# Is the rule for squaring differences a "degenerate" case of the law of cosines?

Tags: trigonometry

Compare $(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab$ (the square of a difference) with $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos{C}$ (the law of cosines), and you will notice the similarity.

So, if one has a (degenerate) "triangle" with three sides $a,b,$ and $c$ for which $c=a-b$, does that mean that the measure of the angle opposite the side with length $c$ is zero degrees, since $\cos{0^{\circ}}=1$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes (as long as $c$ is the longest side), as $\Bbb R$ is a model of Euclidean geometry, with $ab$ the dot product. If $a,\,b$ have the same sign, $C=0^\circ$; if they have different signs, $C=180^\circ$, but the "$ab$" in the cosine rule really means $|a||b|$, which in normal multiplication terms is $-ab$, so it works out.